# Defining or calling an unspecified array with constant entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes one wants to define a function in terms of a set of basis functions when trying to solve a boundary value problem using a finite element approach. However, the coefficients of the basis functions are unknown.

Writing the code using nothing fancy, how might one do this?

If one wants to use "advanced" Python (I'm not at this level yet) I've seen the following:

```python
 import sys
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.integrate import quad
 from scipy.optimize import minimize
 Polynomial = np.polynomial.Polynomial
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 def get_basis(N):
     p1, p2 = Polynomial([1,-1]), Polynomial([1,1])
     basis = [p1**(N-n+1) * p2**(n+1) for n in range(N+1)]
     return basis

 def get_psi(a, basis): 
     return sum([a[i]*p for i,p in enumerate(basis)])
```

which can be found in the model solution to a variational problem for a quantum particle in a box over at Christian Hill's Scientific Computing blog. The problem appears in the first edition of his book "Learning Scientific Programming with Python." Now, I know some Python, but I've not searched through his blog for an answer to my question which is:

what exactly is going on here? It seems that the `get` function
can be used to arbitrarily create an unspecified array of size N+1, but that the `sys` module is needed to this. I've looked up the get function in the textbooks on Python that I have, but they seem to refer to dictionaries. What does `def get_()` mean? What kind of function is it? I have a vague understanding of the `sys` module.

It is an understatement to write that I know Hill's code works, but I don't understand the technical aspects of implement `sys` and `get_basis()` and `get_psi()`. It seems to me that using them allows one to call an unspecified array of coefficients.

I know Hill's code works but I don't understand the technical aspects of implement `sys` and `get_basis()` and `get_psi()`.

p.s. The following comments are included in Hill's code: in the basis function the comment "Return the N+1 basis functions for n = 0, 1, ..., N." is included and in the `psi` function "Return a Polynomial object representing the trial wavefunction expanded
in basis with coefficients a." is included.

Comment: As shown, `get_basis` and `get_psi` don't seem to have any dependency on the `sys` module.  Is there some other code that does?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. Here is a link to the code for the solution. An initial guess is provided for the coefficients, but how he defines an array without specifying its contents stumps me: https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/problems/p84/the-variational-principle-and-the-quantum-mechanical-particle-in-a-box/

Comment: The only dependency of these functions is `numpy`. The complete code in the blog uses `sys.exit()`, but this is unrelated to these two functions. The function `get_basis` returns a list of numpy `Polynomial` objects representing a certain basis of a vector space of polynomials. The function `get_psi` uses a list of basis polynomials and a list of coefficients to create a linear combination of the basis elements with the given coefficients.

Comment: @bb1, so how then does he define the array a without first specifying the values of the elements? Does he just leave the a[i] unspecified in get_psi(a, basis) and then once he provides an initial guess for the values of each a[i] everything is taken care of? Does he even need to define psi as he does?